# How to set up the gateway for wlan0?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, internet, gateway

I am using a private hotspot to connect a Raspberry Py to internet. I've setup the password and the ssid in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file. With this configuration I'm able to connect to the wifi but I can't connect to internet.

```
pi@tenzo /etc $ ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.40.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From tenzo.local (192.168.1.115) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I've asked around and they said it's a gateway issue. Running `traceroute` from a laptop connected to the same network I get:

```
userk@dopamine:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (216.58.212.110), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.43.1 (192.168.43.1)  2.423 ms  5.088 ms  5.084 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.4.129.165 (10.4.129.165)  120.018 ms  120.027 ms  120.020 ms
 4  10.4.129.196 (10.4.129.196)  129.488 ms  129.490 ms  129.471 ms
 5  10.4.129.196 (10.4.129.196)  138.994 ms  141.969 ms  144.439 ms
```

Do you have any advice?

**EDIT 1**
I've added to the `interfaces` the gateway, address and netmask. SEE **EDIT 2**

Now, when I ping google.com I get the same error as before...

This is the output of `route -n`

```
pi@tenzo ~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway       Genmask      Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1   0.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1  0.0.0.0       UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0      255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

**EDIT 2**
This is my interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.1.115
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
        address 192.168.43.235
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.43.1
        wpa-ssid "UserKOnTheNet"
        wpa-psk "xxxxx"
```

This is the output of **traceroute**

```
pi@tenzo ~ $ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.40.7), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  tenzo.local (192.168.1.115)  2995.172 ms !H  2995.058 ms !H  2995.016 ms !H
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gateway would need to be configured in your `interfaces` file; e.g., something like

```
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.x.y
    gateway 192.168.x.z
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

would work (where x is your network number, y the address for your host, and z the address for your gateway). Obviously you need to retain your encryption settings, too.

If you're using dhcp on that interface, then something is wrong with your dhcp server.

**EDIT**: you should also make sure no other network interface has a `gateway` setting, or if it does, that the gateway setting on that interface is correct. A "gateway" or "default gateway" is a machine which offers a connection to the Internet. It is a valid configuration to have a network interface without a `gateway` line if no such host exists on that network connection.

In your case, assuming there is no internet router on the network that `eth0` is linked to, you should ensure that the `iface eth0` stanza looks like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.115
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

i.e., what you already have, but without the `gateway 192.168.1.1` line. (the indentation at the start of the line is optional, but does make the file easier to read).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added what you suggested. Please see my Edit

Comment: did you run `sudo service networking restart` (or reboot your pi) after making that change? If not, the changes you made haven't been activated yet.

Comment: Yes I did it. It was using as gateway address the one of eth0...

Answer (score 1):

By comparing the outputs of the `traceroute google.com` command I noticed that the working laptop connected to the internet throught the same wifi network had the first hop with the correct gateway address 192.168.43.1 and the Raspberry Pi had `1  tenzo.local (192.168.1.115)` which is the static address of the eth0 interface.

I solved the problem using @Wouter Verhelst 's suggestion and disabling the eth0 interface with

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
```

Now the internet connection works!

Comment: you can also change it so that the line `gateway 192.168.1.1` is removed from the `iface eth0` stanza. That line is wrong, and won't work, and without it you should be able to use network over eth0 even if wireless is enabled.

Comment: Could you add this suggestion to you answer? How should I configure eth0 then?